# Position one image over another but where both move together when browser width adjusted

Tags: html, css

I want to have two images. One over top of the other. The images must be centered horizontally within their div container and if the browser window width is adjusted, the image over top of the other remains in the same relative position over the one below it. I've tried a number of things but haven't had success. I can't even get either image centered horizontally either. Here is the basics:

http://jsfiddle.net/AndroidDev/gxpSX/

```
<div style="width:100%">
    <div style="float: left; position:absolute; margin:auto">
        <img src="http://www.majhost.com/gallery/shaucker/Requests/red_rectangle-489x328.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; position:absolute; z-index:3000">
        <img src="http://www.avforums.com/forums/attachments/gran-turismo-ps3/206363d1286966503-gt5-wallpapers-artwork-dial-up-beware-yellow_buttonpsd.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/gxpSX/2/

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center; position:relative;">
    <img src="http://www.majhost.com/gallery/shaucker/Requests/red_rectangle-489x328.png" />
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0">
        <img src="http://www.avforums.com/forums/attachments/gran-turismo-ps3/206363d1286966503-gt5-wallpapers-artwork-dial-up-beware-yellow_buttonpsd.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does it. I don't understand why text-align is used. I thought that is for text. But clearly that is not the case.

Comment: It is for text, but it's also for inline content such as images.

Comment: `text-align` at times can be interpreted as **contents align** as in the `align` attribute in element .i.e: `<div align="left"></div>` in css you'll say: `div {text-align:center}`... PS: Note that the `align` attribute in elements is deprecated..

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the float property is that it allows elements to wrap around each other. I don't think you'll be able to achieve what you want to using float.

Comment: You did try thirtydot's solution did you?

Comment: I dont think float does much anyway in conjunction with `position: absolute;`. It's just seen as an absolute positioned element and float is ignored.